# Connect dots in separate d3 graphs

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a d3 graph that is a series of dots on a horizontal line (for ease, let's say a red one, blue one, green one). Not too tough.
I have several of these graphs stacked on top of each other. Easy.

A solid line then needs to connect all the red dots vertically across the different graphs. This is where my mind explodes.

- Is it possible to draw a line across multiple graphs.
- Do I make a single graph that sits over all of the individual graphs.
- Is there a way to find the location of a node in a different graph and draw a line towards that one.
- Do I need to calculate a phantom node based on the height of a row and some trigonometry to draw the line.

Any suggestions of approaches would be ***greatly*** appreciated. I am in pre-dev stage, trying to figure out level of effort for the designers who are asking this.

Comment: if you draw a simple image of what you want. This text is very vague. You can't draw lines between svg's, and what do you mean with a graph (a collection of dots connected with lines)?

Comment: you can make element of an SVG extend outside of the SVG itself, although I probably wouldn't do this.  It sounds like you should create 1 SVG, with multiple 'g' elements per 'graph', and then overlay what you need on top of those